# Generating random UUIDs in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, guid, uuid

I am stuck in a strange predicament. I need to generate UUIDs in my Linux program (which I distribute using RPMs). I do not want to add another dependency to my application by requiring the user to install libuuid (seems like libuuid isn't included in most Linux distros, like CentOS).

Isn't there a standard Linux system call which generates UUIDs (like say, in Windows there CoCreateGuid)? What does the command uuidgen use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments!

I went through each one, and here's what suited my requirement the best:

What I needed was just plain time-based UUIDs which were generated from random numbers once for every user who installed the application. UUID version 4 as specified in  RFC 4122 was exactly it. I went through a the algorithm suggested, and came up with a pretty simple solution which would work in Linux as well as Windows (Maybe its too simplistic, but it does satisfy the need!):

```
srand(time(NULL));

sprintf(strUuid, "%x%x-%x-%x-%x-%x%x%x", 
    rand(), rand(),                 // Generates a 64-bit Hex number
    rand(),                         // Generates a 32-bit Hex number
    ((rand() & 0x0fff) | 0x4000),   // Generates a 32-bit Hex number of the form 4xxx (4 indicates the UUID version)
    rand() % 0x3fff + 0x8000,       // Generates a 32-bit Hex number in the range [0x8000, 0xbfff]
    rand(), rand(), rand());        // Generates a 96-bit Hex number
```

Comment: Sure! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I had no idea! I hadn't accepted the answer because I'd come up with it on my own and thought it too simplistic!!

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confusing - the term "time-based UUID" is not version 4 but version 1. On the theoretical side, using modulus 0x3fff would not give you a smooth distribution of outputs, though I doubt it would have any practical implications.

Comment: so if this function is called twice on the same second, it will return the same value. How do you manage that?

Comment: very simple working answer... thank you. also it is portable and can work directly on many platforms.

Comment: @themoondothshine thanks a million. Stuck all afternoon on HP-UX trying to generate a UUID and you have come up with this super elegant solution. I have a chocolate cake in the fridge, I would gladly overnight it to you as a thank you!

Answer (score 28):

Am I missing something?  Can't you:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
```

Comment: May not be portable to other Linux systems.

Comment: How expensive is that? Isn't it a hardware based entropy pool for Linux? Those are usually expensive.

Answer (score 12):

A good way I found (for linux dev) is to `#include <uuid/uuid.h>`. Then you have a few functions you can call:

```
void uuid_generate(uuid_t out);
void uuid_generate_random(uuid_t out);
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason why you can't just link statically to libuuid?

Comment: libuuid appears to be LGPL, so the OP's application would also have to be LGPL. Dynamic linking avoids the license requirement. [Source](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid). Unless you're talking about a different libuuid.

Answer (score 3):

I can't post comments on answers yet, but I'd just like to point out that the accepted answer's use of rand() won't work well at all on Windows, where RAND_MAX is defined as 0x7fff, giving just 15 bits of randomness. On Linux it's higher, but looks like it's 0x7fffffff, giving 31 bits of randomness, still missing 1 bit to full 32 bit length.

The safest way to use rand() would be to rely on the fact that the lowest guaranteed RAND_MAX value anywhere is going to be 0x7fff - call it multiple times, shifting left by 15 bits and OR'ing with a new value, until the required amount of random bits is produced.

Also, the format string in `sprintf` should have width specified, so leading zeros are taken into account (the widths are based on the mentioned bits in the respective argument comment):

```
sprintf(strUuid, "%08x%08x-%08x-%08x-%08x-%08x%08x%08x", 
    rand(), rand(),                 // Generates a 64-bit Hex number
    rand(),                         // Generates a 32-bit Hex number
    ((rand() & 0x0fff) | 0x4000),   // Generates a 32-bit Hex number of the form 4xxx (4 indicates the UUID version)
    rand() % 0x3fff + 0x8000,       // Generates a 32-bit Hex number in the range [0x8000, 0xbfff]
    rand(), rand(), rand());        // Generates a 96-bit Hex number
```

Furthermore - the code produces 256 bit values, rather than 128 bit values compatible with
RFC 4122 UUIDs.

And final comment:

```
rand() % 0x3fff + 0x8000,       // Generates a 32-bit Hex number in the range [0x8000, 0xbfff]
```

due to the modulo operator, the actual range produced is [0x8000, 0xbffe]. The `%` should have been `&` (or 0x3fff should have been 0x4000 if using `%`, but division is always a more expensive operation than bitwise AND).

Here's a revised version of the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdint>

uint32_t rand32()
{
    return ((rand() & 0x3) << 30) | ((rand() & 0x7fff) << 15) | (rand() & 0x7fff);
}

bool gen_uuid4(char dst[37], size_t len)
{
    int n = snprintf(dst, len, "%08x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%08x", 
        rand32(),                         // Generates a 32-bit Hex number
        rand32() & 0xffff,                // Generates a 16-bit Hex number
        ((rand32() & 0x0fff) | 0x4000),   // Generates a 16-bit Hex number of the form 4xxx (4 indicates the UUID version)
        (rand32() & 0x3fff) + 0x8000,     // Generates a 16-bit Hex number in the range [0x8000, 0xbfff]
        rand32() & 0xffff, rand32());     // Generates a 48-bit Hex number
        
    return n >= 0 && n < len;             // Success only when snprintf result is a positive number and the provided buffer was large enough.
}

int main()
{
    char strUuid[37];
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    bool success = gen_uuid4(strUuid, sizeof(strUuid));
    
    printf("%s\n", success ? strUuid : "UUID generation failed!");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps ooid will help? http://ooid.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

No system call exists in POSIX to generate UUID, but I guess you can find somewhere a BSD/MIT code to generate the UUID. ooid is released under the Boost software license, which according to wikipedia, is a permissive license in the style of BSD/MIT. Then you can just paste it into your application, without any need to add dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

`uuidgen` on my ubuntu linux dist works just fine.